# Binding .AAR Library in Xamarin.Android with javadoc doesn't adopt parameter names

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.android, aar

I've been trying to include the javadoc to a .aar library so I don't have to manually edit every method parameter name in the MetaData.xml file.
So far I've done everything suggested in [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11121/including-javadocs-in-a-binding-library) thread but I still can't get it to work.

I generated the javadoc like so:

`javadoc -subpackages at -notree -noindex -nohelp -nonavbar -d javadoc`

In my build output, the JarToXml task looks like this:

```
1>Task "JarToXml"
1>  JarToXml Task
1>    JavaOptions: 
1>    JavaMaximumHeapSize: 
1>    AndroidSdkDirectory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\
1>    AndroidApiLevel: 17
1>    MonoAndroidToolsDirectory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
1>    JavaSdkDirectory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\
1>    OutputFile: obj\Release\api.xml
1>    DroidDocPaths: 
1>    JavaDocPaths: JavaDocs\javadoc\
1>    Java7DocPaths: JavaDocs\javadoc\
1>    JavaDocs: {0}
1>      JavaDocs\javadoc\index.html
1>    AndroidApiLevel: 17
1>    LibraryProjectJars:
1>      obj\Release\__library_projects__\*.jar
1>    SourceJars:
1>      obj\Release\library_project_jars\\classes.jar
1>    ReferenceJars:
1>      C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\embedded\classes.jar
1>      C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\21.0.3\embedded\libs\internal_impl-21.0.3.jar
```

I'm suspicious of the build output of the "BuildDocumentation" task, because on the one hand, it adds members with p0, p1, etc. as parameter names, and on the other hand, it doesn't find the right javadoc members.

```
1>  Member Added: protected virtual void SetLevelsForAutoFlash (int p0, int p1, int p2, int p3);
1>  Member Added: public virtual void SetVibrateOnResult (bool p0);
....
1>      Updating member anchor: hasNewImage()
1>  javadoc-to-mdoc: Could not find JavaDoc for member: hasNewImage().
1>      Updating member anchor: getNewImage()
1>  javadoc-to-mdoc: Could not find JavaDoc for member: getNewImage().
....
```

I've set up a property for both JavaDocPaths and Java7DocPaths in my .csproject just to be sure, and I added the javadoc to a subfolder JavaDocs/javadoc in my project, where I set the build action of index.html to JavaDocIndex.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Java7DocPaths>JavaDocs\javadoc\</Java7DocPaths>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <JavaDocPaths>JavaDocs\javadoc\</JavaDocPaths>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 btw. What am I missing here?

Cheers, EtePetete

(PS: I've tried to post this issue twice now in the Xamarin forum, but they seem to reject my question without any reason)